# Syncing users & roles to Keycloak over LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, keycloak

The issue I'm facing is that I tested with creating a `role-ldap-mapper` with a filter that would only import the roles I'm after. This works, I'm able to sync LDAP roles to Keycloak. However, when I then try to import users, I expect Keycloak to obey the filter I specified in the `role-ldap-mapper`, but it won't. It happily imports all of the roles that I thought I was preventing with my custom filter, and also associates the imported users with those unwanted roles.

This is the filter I'm using for mapping the roles.

[image]

I was expecting that the filter is applied when the user is synchronized over LDAP, such that I *only* see my selected subset of roles, and the user -> role assignments also reflected.